# Database schema and logic for this

Tags: mysql, database

I am trying to create a timetable for classes in MySQL. The columns are the days of the week and the rows are the time intervals ( i.e. 7:00 - 8:00 ). I am also trying to have 30-minute time intervals and when a particular subject is 2 hours, it will span 4 rows. Each cell contains the name of the course and room. This is part of a small program I am trying to develop. So far, I know what data to insert but I'm stuck on creating the right database schema. Really need the logic on how to get this started (i.e. what data types should I use ). Thanks!

Comment: Database tables are not spreadsheets. There's nothing logically different between what might be stored for 7:00-8:00 on a Monday compared to what might be stored for 7:00-8:00 on a Friday. Both items ought to be stored in the same column. This would point to one column storing day and another storing time spans, and a final column storing "what happens on that day during that time span".

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I've already done inserting all the data with that database design you mentioned above. I am then stuck at trying to display the data in a timetable format using HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How does this sound:

```
CREATE TABLE TimeTable (
    ID int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Subject varchar(32) NOT NULL,
    Room varchar(8) NOT NULL,
    StartTime datetime NOT NULL,
    EndTime datetime NOT NULL,
    Day enum('Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday') NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (ID)
);
```

You only store the data about the subjects.

The other stuff you mentioned is really down to whatever language you're using to output the data. You can't really put intervals in the middle of a database. As Damien_The_Unbeliever said, databases aren't exactly spreadsheets.

Hope this make sense.

Comment: You could have a composite primary key instead of the `ID` field: `(StartTime, Day)`.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I am trying to output the timetable in HTML, which I think is flexible enough to handle this kind of table. Thanks!

Comment: @Cobra_Fast nice +1 but as a side note this PRIMARY KEY is 12 or 13 byte large per record. if you use storage engine InnoDB it will add the clusted index (in this case the PRIMARY KEY) data to every Secondary index. This is also the reason why InnoDB is faster for looking up Secondary indexes vs MyISAM, but it needs more disk spaces and a larger buffer pool too to it good.

Answer (score 0):

You can set one column for day (you can value days from 1 to 7), one column for starting time and one column for finish time. This way your queries will become more simple.

Example:

```
Day    |  Start    | Finish
-----------------------------
1       8:30         12:00
1       13:00        15:00
```

This will also come in handy when you don't want to stuck with 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

> The columns are the days of the week and the rows are the time intervals ( i.e. 7:00 - 8:00 )

That's a bad start. Your columns should be properties of a single lesson and your rows should be all the different lessons throughout the week.

Your columns could be `Day of Week`, `Lesson of Day`, `Duration`, `Subject`, `Room`, `Teacher`, et cetera. In this example, your primary key would be `(Day of Week, Lesson of Day)`.

This way, if you want the schedule for a particular day you just select everything with `Day of Week = 2` to get the schedule for Tuesday for example.

> Each cell contains the name of the course and room.

This also defys the laws of normalization. You should always have no more than one value per "cell".

> Really need the logic on how to get this started (i.e. what data types should I use )

Use the most intuitive type. When you store a number choose `integer`, when storing few characters choose `varchar(n)`, when using lots of characters use `text` and so on...

Comment: Thanks for the idea. What I meant by the `columns are the days of the week...` was the display which can be done using HTML. It's not necessarily the format of the MySQL table. Sorry if the question was confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I would create it this way where it is normalized and gives more chance to expand this app further.
Tables (attributes):

1. `timeslots(id, start_time, end_time)`
2. `subjects(id, name)`
3. `timetable(timeslot_id, subject_id)`

Comment: Link tables are unnecessary. There won't be enough variation in the time slots to justify the use of these.

Comment: It might be unnecessary in this use case, however, when a more complex use case is experienced a 1 table database (spreadsheet style) may not be suffice. This is just to cater for future expansion its probably not the best for now.